# Git submodule is in "detached head" state after cloning and submodule update

Tags: git

When I clone my git repo, one of the submodules is in a branch with a strange name, which I think means it has a "**detached head**" (I'm not even sure what that means).

If I checkout my main branch for the submodule, then run "`git submodule update --init --recursive`" it happens again.

Does anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Git submodules are (almost) always in that state.  "Detached head" means that the git working-directory is "at" a specified commit (by commit-ID) rather than "on a branch" ("on a branch" = at the commit-ID specified by a branch name, with the branch name moving automatically to the latest branch tip as new commits are added).  See [Git submodules: Specify a branch/tag](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1777854/1256452).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The contents of git directories are stored in simple text file manifests (i.e. directory listings) called "trees" that look like the following, where blobs are the contents of files, and trees are yet more trees like this one:

```
100644 blob 0c31be662540ce902cee106f86bfdeef519fc662    .gitignore
100644 blob 1d364edf530c2238e79162bf2d9f30c2af610347    .gitmodules
040000 tree fc6bc39202ec20228e9135cd426110c558b625cd    foo
040000 tree 2f9fc460f3a2370ed45b39b2bcaaf9b6e746b823    bar
```

If bar was a submodule, instead of merely a directory, however, the tree containing it would be listed like this:

```
100644 blob 0c31be662540ce902cee106f86bfdeef519fc662    .gitignore
100644 blob 1d364edf530c2238e79162bf2d9f30c2af610347    .gitmodules
040000 tree fc6bc39202ec20228e9135cd426110c558b625cd    foo
040000 commit 2f9fc460f3a2370ed45b39b2bcaaf9b6e746b823  bar
```

Note that instead of bar being a tree, it's now a commit (in a submodule). This is all git stores about a submodule at the tree/commit level, so it can't know what branch a commit was on. In fact, storing branch names can't work. They can change. Also, if you check out an old commit in your repo that needs to roll the submodule back as well, should the branch move back in the submodule? That would cast the commits after that new branch location into unreferenced territory.

The branches are for humans to use, to make sense of the DAG, and where particular lines of thought are. Git doesn't care how we refer to the commits. It needs a concrete location so you can safely move the containing repo around, and know that the submodule will always be checked out to where it was at that time. The only truth is the hash.

Answer (score 49):

A submodule is *always* checked out as a detached HEAD (see "[Why did git detach my head?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)"), since the index of the parent repo contains only the SHA1 as a [special entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309) [in its index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309), as explained by [Gary Fixler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/955926/gary-fixler)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20796019/6309).

Even if you [configure your submodule to follow a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309) (or [convert an existing submodule to follow a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309)), a `git submodule update --remote` would checkout the latest SHA1 of that remote branch, but the result would *by default* be a detached HEAD.
Only by adding `--merge` or `--rebase` to that command (`git submodule update --remote (--merge/--rebase)`) would you get a non-detached HEAD, as seen in [Simba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5101148/simba)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57121881/6309)): by default, the `master` branch.

If you don't update that way (`git submodule update --remote (--merge/--rebase)`), then you need to go in that submodule and make a branch yourself there.

If you want to contribute to said submodule (making new commits in it), it is a good idea to create a new branch.

```
cd mySubmodule
git checkout -b aNewBranch
# work
git add .
git commit -m "new commits"
git push -u origin aNewBranch

# record the new submodule state in the parent repo:
cd ..
git add mySubmodule
git commit -m "new state of mySubmodule"
git push
```

---

Note for Git 2.16 (Q1 2018): "`git checkout --recursive`" may overwrite and rewind the history of the branch that happens to be checked out in submodule
repositories, which might not be desirable.
Detach the `HEAD` but still allow the recursive checkout to succeed in such a case.

See [commit 57f22bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/57f22bf9979c94f66c3596fb28d0588c1edc2f8d) (28 Jul 2017), and [commit 3ef2538](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ef253803211f5ec38c88635bfd50f91ccd98e16) (24 Jul 2017) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0b75572](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0b75572a1b9f601b751d431faea55f492ea92ac9), 06 Dec 2017)</sup>

> ### recursive submodules: detach HEAD from new state
>
> When a submodule is on a branch and in its superproject you run a
>   recursive checkout, the branch of the submodule is updated to what the
>   superproject checks out.
>   This is very unexpected in the current model of Git as e.g. '`submodule update`' always detaches the submodule HEAD.
>
> Despite having plans to have submodule HEADS not detached in the future,
>   the current behavior is really bad as it doesn't match user expectations
>   and it is not checking for loss of commits (only to be recovered via the
>   reflog).
>
> Detach the HEAD unconditionally in the submodule when updating it.

Comment: What is the `-u` argument you have added?

Comment: @Thomas It is the upstream branch (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4879224/6309): see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309.

Comment: I **just** read [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules#Working-on-a-Project-with-Submodules), too, in the Git Book about the `--set-upstream` command.

Comment: @Thomas the point is, in a submodule, you need to push your changes before recording the new SHA1 of said submodule in the parent repo. If you don't, a clone of that parent repo would try to clone the submodule to a non-existent SHA1. And to push easily, it is best to set an upstream branch, in order for the submodule branch to know where to push and to which remote branch to push.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a **`branch` option** in `.gitmodule` is **NOT related** to the detached behavior of submodules at all.

From `git submodule --help`, **HEAD detached is the default behavior** of `git submodule update --remote`.

First, there's **no need to specify a branch to be tracked**. `origin/master` is the default branch to be tracked.

> --remote
>
> Instead of using the superproject's recorded SHA-1 to update the submodule, use the status of the submodule's remote-tracking branch. The remote used is branch's remote (`branch.<name>.remote`), **defaulting to `origin`**. The remote branch used **defaults to `master`**.

### Why

So why is HEAD detached after `update`? Because the **default behavior of `submodule.$name.update` is `checkout`**.

> --checkout
>
> Checkout the commit recorded in the superproject on a **detached HEAD** in the submodule. This is the **default behavior**, the main use of this option is to override `submodule.$name.update` when set to a value other than `checkout`.

### How

If you want the submodule merged with remote branch automatically, use `--merge` or `--rebase`.

> --merge
>
> This option is **only valid for the update** command. Merge the commit recorded in the superproject into the current branch of the submodule. If this option is given, the submodule's HEAD will **not be detached**.
>
> --rebase
>
> Rebase the current branch onto the commit recorded in the superproject. If this option is given, the submodule's HEAD will **not be detached**.

All you need to do is,

```sh
git submodule update --remote --merge
# or
git submodule update --remote --rebase
```

There's also an option to make `--merge` or `--rebase` as the default behavior of `git submodule update`, by setting `submodule.$name.update` to `merge` or `rebase`.

Here's an example about how to config the default update behavior of submodule update in `.gitmodule`.

```
[submodule "bash/plugins/dircolors-solarized"]
    path = bash/plugins/dircolors-solarized
    url = https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized.git
    update = merge # <-- this is what you need to add
```

My whole answer is based on the manual. `git submodule --help`.

Comment: It does not work really. git version in Mac git version 2.24.2 (Apple Git-127)

Answer (score 3):

For users of [Sourcetree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) - you will observe the same behavior - a clone will give you submodules in a detached state. As [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) mentions [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20797186/1808261) if you want to contribute to the submodule you need to perform some extra steps.

Besides creating a new branch from the point of the submodule SHA-1, in most cases you will simply want to checkout the head of the existing branch. This will be master unless the sub-module is configured to follow a specific branch.

You can either open each submodule and manually checkout their corresponding branches, or you can create a custom action to do it for you (**recursively!**):

[image]

**Script to Run**

```
cmd
```

**Parameters**

```
/c %LOCALAPPDATA%\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin\sh.exe --login -i -c "git pull; git submodule foreach -q --recursive 'toplevel=\"$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)\"; branch=\"$(git config -f $toplevel/.gitmodules submodule.$name.branch)\"; [ \"$branch\" = \"\" ] && branch=master; git checkout $branch; git fetch; git merge FETCH_HEAD;'"""
```

This will check for any submodules in your project and checkout the branch that they point to (or master if they don't specify a branch). It is recursive, so any submodules that contain submodules will also be handled.

As I found out in [an earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29265341/1808261), the extra pair of quotes on the end are required.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, none of the previously posted answers actually worked for me. Hence, I created a simple script:

```
#/bin/bash
git submodule init
git submodule update
cd <submodule>
git checkout <branch>
```

this actually checks out the submodule commit recorded in the superproject without a detached head.