# What is a subproject commit?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to add the Laravel files to a Github repo.

I ran

`$ git clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git`

The files show up fine locally but do not show up when I push to github:

[image]

The commit shows:

[image]

How can I add the laravel files to my github repo? Also, what is a subproject commit?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

A submodule commit is a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, [special entry recorded in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309), created when you add a submodule to your repo;

It records the SHA1 currently referenced by the parent repo.

A **`git submodule update --init`** is enough to populate the laravel subdirectory in your repo.

Once it is filled, note that your submodule repo is in a [detached HEAD mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20797186/6309).

[As shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38278503/6309), when switching branches in the parent repo, your submodule gitlink will change accordingly, but your submodule content won't change until you make again a git submodule update (after the `git checkout`)

Answer (score 23):

It means the repository uses [Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

To pull down the Laravel code, try

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Submodules are notoriously prickly; I recommend reading up on them before working too much on a project that uses them. The link above should be a good starting point.