# How to list git submodules that have not been pushed to origin?

Tags: git, push, git-submodules, git-push

Sometimes I forget to push a git submodule. Is there a way to show which git submodules are ahead of origin, that have not been pushed?

Answer (score 4):

A simple status on each submodules could give you a good representation of their respective state:

```
git submodule foreach "git status || true"
```

See "[Use `git submodule foreach` with function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83468/use-git-submodule-foreach-with-function)" for more sophisticated scripts to run in combination of a `git submodule foreach` command.

That will show push status only if:

- [your module is configured to follow a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309). (Otherwise, a submodule is checked out as a detached head, and the commit status would be empty, the push status non-existent)

  ```
  git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<path>.branch <branch>
  git submodule update --init --remote
  ```
- a branch has been checked out (and commits done)

  ```
  cd asubmodule
  git checkout master
  # add and commit
  ```

(See "[Git submodule is in “detached head” state after cloning and submodule update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20797186/6309)")

Then the command would work (for instance for the ['`compose`' submodule of the project `b2d`](https://github.com/VonC/b2d)):

```
VonC@voncvb MINGW64 /c/Users/VonC/prog/b2d (master)
$ git submodule foreach "git status || true"
Entering 'compose'
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: @adrelanos It will show push status (I just tested it), but my answers lacked the necessary steps for that push status to be visible. I have amended my answer.