# Pull and rebase from a remote that's been split into submodules

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I'm collaborating on a GitHub project (I've forked the repo) that has recently been re-structured into `submodules`.

Earlier I would `git stash` my changes, do a `git pull --rebase shared_origin master`, and then perform `git stash pop` to continue working. After commiting changes to my local repo, I would push them to my fork of the shared repo using `git push my_origin development` and then create a `PR`.

Now that the project has been split into submodules, how do I perform a pull rebase that replicates entire repo (including all submodules), re-apply my (unmerged) changes and continue with my development?

Please do consider the possibility where the file(s) I had changed have been moved to a different directory as a part of submodule-restructuring.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the option [`pull --recurse-submodule=yes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#git-pull---no-recurse-submodulesyeson-demandno).

And don't forget you can stash and rebase by default on a git pull.

```
git config pull.rebase true
git config rebase.autoStash true
```

Actually, combine that [with the config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-fetchrecurseSubmodules):

```
git config fetch.recurseSubmodules true
```

And now, a simple `git pull` from the parent repo (the one referencing all those submodules) is enough.

Note: submodules are by default in [detached HEAD mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20797186/6309), so make sure they have checked out a branch first, and you have done some commits locally in them, if you want the rebase to actually do something in said submodules.